# I can't set the brightness of my system

Tags: laptop, brightness, backlight

Afetr some updates of my system Ubuntu 16.04 LTS; the brightness is higher, I'haven't possibility to set it, It doesn't appear on power manager.
I've installed **xbacklight** and set this configuration

```
xbacklight =50    
xbacklight +10    
xbacklight -10
```

After the reboot, nothing change, this dialog box prompts [dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJSEm.png)
That mean : Impossible to set the configuration
So  I installed **Indicator brightness** to have to set it in the system tray, but i have this notification:`No backlights were found on your system`
I do `ls /sys/class/backlight/`
It returns nothing
I decided do to use laptop-mode-tools, but I can't use it because the precendent command return nothing ( no files or directories in /sys/class/backlight/)
Maybe this can help to:

```
lspci | grep "VGA compatible controller"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
```

I think I did more effort for my English level.

I need your helps to solve this problem.
My eyes are suffering actually
thanks;

This the output of `lshw`

```
 *-display NON-RÉCLAMÉ
         description: VGA compatible controller
         produit: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
         fabriquant: Intel Corporation
         identifiant matériel: 2
         information bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
         version: 0b
         bits: 64 bits
         horloge: 33MHz
         fonctionnalités: vga_controller bus_master cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
         ressources: mémoire:b2000000-b23fffff mémoire:a0000000-afffffff portE/S:6000(taille=64)
```

Comment: It seems like a problem with your graphic drivers. Please, post the output of `lshw` (here, look for `*-display`).

Comment: @hackthatos for the future, you are able to add comments to answers to your question.  You do not need to post comments as answers.  Look for an "add a comment" button underneath each answer, you should be able to see it.  You can click that, and then add comments to answers asking for clarification of the answer or results you get from a command they said to run.

Comment: My  question is when can I consider my poste like an **Answer**  or comment.  Excuse me of my ignorance, Everything is complelety  different here from where I'm coming.  And i'm suprised  when @JuanjoSalvador said: "this is not a forum"

Answer (score 0):

an alternative way to set the brightness is to use xrandr

```
xrandr --output $DISPALY --brightness $VALUE
```

$DISPLAY is the name of your connected display, you can get a list of all displays with

`xrandr -q | grep "connected"`

replace $VALUE with your desired level of brightness.

example :   `xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness .4`

Comment: Thank for your answer, this the output of the command: `~$ xrandr -q | grep` `"connected" xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default` `default connected primary 1366x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm` Please, what else ?